# Scene content is shown in game player but not shown in windows build

Tags: unity-game-engine

The scene content is shown in game player but not shown in windows build.

Could anyone suggest what can cause to this kind of problem, Or suggest ways to troubleshoot it?

Please note that :

- The scene is properly defined in the build settings
- I am using windows 10
- I am building for windows
- The scene contains some sprites with physics , an imported character with animations (I imported it from the asset store) , a UI canvas with a button, and some scripts that attached to the objects.
- The scripts do almost nothing.
- The game content is properly shown inside the game player (Unity's Editor player) the problem is only with the build.
- When running the build output , Unity's splash screen is shown and then the scene is loaded but its content isn't shown.
- I changed the camera background color , and the color is indeed changed in the build , it's just the scene content that isn't shown.
- I added a UI canvas with a button , the button is shown.
- I am using Unity 5.5.1f1
- it is a 2d project

Comment: With everything you have tried it is almost impossible to help you without access to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding the scene to `Scenes in Build` screen.

Go to File->Build Settings and in the dialog make sure your scene has a check mark on the left.

When running in Editor Unity runs whatever scene you are working on, but when building a player you need to include the scene in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you read my notes? Anyway, I tried that before posting the question , it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I deleted the camera and created a new one. It solved the problem.